# What type of ants are these?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, ant

I live in NYC and these fellas started popping out near my computer screen and desk. They don't seem interested in food as my sister usually leaves candy wrappers around. They however are stinky, I tried to catch one with a tape and I can smell the odors they give off like 4 inches away. They got these stingers on their butt so I think they could be a species of fire ant. They're also really tiny. As shown on a q tip here.

[image]
[image]

<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>

Finally could these be bites? They are really itchy and I get them overnight.

[image]

Comment: They look like termite, rather than ants.

Comment: @JackRod all wrong for a termite.

Comment: A close up on one of the ones that is curled up and dead would be a big help. a side shot would be best.

Comment: Many, ant species have stinger.

Answer (score 0):

odorous house ant

Without a better picture I can't be certain but based on what anatomy we can see and you mentioning smell I would guess the odorous house ant.

They do stink when crushed, it should smell like blue cheese and turpentine.  They are common house pest in NYC drawn by sweets and water.

They do not sting or bite so they are likely non connected but again without a better picture it is hard to be certain. I suggest asking about medical concerns on the medical stack as they are off topic here.

As a small consolation at least they are a native ant species.

Answer (score -4):

They should be Red Imported Fireants.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_imported_fire_ant
[image]

Comment: thorax shape is all wrong and head is too small for red imported fire ants. red imported fire ants should have pretty prominent petiole